# Type Inference in Java with Iterators?

Tags: java, collections, iterator, javac, type-inference

Regarding type inference in Java, I have the following small snippet of code:

```
ArrayList<String> projectNameList = new ArrayList<String>(3);
projectNameList.add("Joe");
projectNameList.add("Jim");
projectNameList.add("Josh");

Iterator it = names.iterator();

while(it.hasNext()){
   System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

I get a compile error when I try to print the names saying Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to String

I know that to fix this all I need to do is explicitly cast the Object to a String, or by explicitly declaring that the type of elements returned by this iterator are of type String, like so:

```
Iterator it<String> = names.iterator();
```

But I would have thought that the javac compiler would be clever enough to infer the type returned by the iterator are Strings, seen as the iterator() method is called on an ArrayList of Strings.

Any reason why this type inference does not take place?

Comment: I don't believe your example gives that error.

Comment: You'll actually get an error that `projectNameList` isn't declared. If you fix that you won't get any compile error at all.

Comment: Please post your actual code

Comment: Apologies there was a typo in there, the list is declared with the name projectNameList. Updated my question.

Comment: [I still don't believe it gives that error.](http://ideone.com/2IKwhv)

Comment: @fulhamHead Maybe you should run the code and see what happens before you post it.

Comment: unfortunately, the compiler is not that clever :( ... yet

Answer (score 2):

`Iterator` is also a generic type.

You need to declare it as `Iterator<String> it = names.iterator();` to reference its elements as `String`s  without casting.

Declaring it as a raw type will actually tell the compiler you want your reference to be an `Iterator<Object>`.

As mentioned by others, you won't get a compiler error by just printing the elements of your raw `Iterator` - you will if you reference a non-existing `projectNameList` variable instead of, say, `names`.